# Threads and the addres space

Tags: multithreading, process, stack, memory-address

I have the following programs :

```html
char **ptr; /* global */
int main()
{
 int i;
 pthread_t tid;
 char *msgs[N] = {
 "Hello from foo",
 "Hello from bar"
 };
 ptr = msgs;
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
 Pthread_create(&tid,
 NULL,
 thread,
 (void *)i);
 Pthread_exit(NULL); 
 }
```

```html
/* thread routine */
void *thread(void *vargp)
{
 int myid = (int)vargp;
 static int svar = myid;
 f1 (myid, svar);
 printf("[%d]: %s (svar=%d)\n",
 myid, ptr[myid], ++svar);
}
/* subroutine f1 */
void f1(id, id2)
{
 If (id == id2){
 something();
 }else{
 somethingelse();
 }
}
```

And I had a few questions about :

1) Where is thread() stored in the “address space”?

2) How many copies of the variable “myid” do we have and where are they
stored?

3) How many copies of the variable “svar” do we have and where is it stored?

4) After thread 1 calls f1() which subroutine (something() or somethingelse())
will be called next?

5) How many copies of ptr (defined external to main()) do we have?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Where is thread() stored in the “address space”?

Wherever the compiler/linker/OS decide to put it. Typically some form of "code segment". There is usually one per module, but there may be more, depending on the compiler/linker/OS configuration.

> 2) How many copies of the variable “myid” do we have and where are
>   they stored?

2 copies. You create 2 threads, and each has its own copy of `myid` on its stack.

> 3) How many copies of the variable “svar” do we have and where is it stored?

There is 1 copy of `svar`; it's a `static` variable. It will be stored in a global data segment. This may be the same data segment as variables declared at global scope, or it may be separate, depending on the compiler/linker/OS configuration.

> 4) After thread 1 calls f1() which subroutine (something() or somethingelse()) > will be called next?

The first thread to execute the `static int svar=myid` line will set `svar`; the second thread through will leave `svar` unchanged (assuming C++11-style thread-safe statics --- on older versions of MSVC, or gcc with thread-safe statics disabled this is a data race and undefined behaviour)

This may be thread 1 or thread 2. Whichever thread is "first" will then call `something`, while the other thread will call `somethingelse`.

> 5) How many copies of ptr (defined external to main()) do we have?

One. It is a global variable.

Comment: Re, "Wherever the compiler/linker/OS decide to put it."  Yes, that's true, but you could add that in most environments, there is, by default, one "code/constant" "segment/section" where all of the application's executable code goes, and most operating systems will load that into one or more read-only pages in the process's address space.